# Convert from string to datatime in sql

Tags: sql

I have a field named duedate and data type is string. I want to compare that field with current date. I used below code:

```
select itemid from issue where CONVERT(datetime, duedate, 105) < '20/11/2016'
```

i got error like "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

please help me out.

Comment: why is this tagged C#?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (CONVERT and that date/time handling is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select itemid from issue where CONVERT(nvarchar(12), duedate, 105) < '20/11/2016'
```